Usando System.setOut en IntelliJ
Necesito enviar la salida de la consola a una variable String, estoy usando IntelliJ-idea, la salida de la consola la produce JShell.eval()
alguien sabrá como hacerlo?
Es decir todo lo que se imprima con System.out.println o print quisiera que se guardara en una variable String producto de la ejecución de código con JShell.eval()

PAra obtener con la salida de código que se obtiene de JShell.eval() , deberías usar ByteArrayOutputStream
    JShell jshell = JShell.create();

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream originalOut = System.out; 
    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(byteArrayOStream);
    System.setOut(printStream); 
    jshell.eval("System.out.println(25 + 35);");
    System.out.flush();
    System.setOut(originalOut);

    //* Convierte salida a String
    String consoleOutput = byteArrayOStream.toString();


Puedes obtener la salida de JShell.eval() redirigiendo System.out a un ByteArrayOutputStream y luego recuperarla como un String.

Hola Stefano, bienvenido y gracias por colaborar, podrías dar un ejemplo de implementación?.
